# Why did Kafka Consumer re-processed all the records since last 2 months?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

In one of the instances, when the consumer service was restarted, it leads to re-processing all the records which were sent to Kafka.

```
Kafka Broker: 0.10.0.1
Kafka producer Service: Springboot version 1.4.3.Release
Kafka Consumer Springboot Service: Springboot version 2.2.0.Release
```

Now for investigating this issue, I want to recreate this scenario again in the dev/local environment which is not happening!!!

What can be the probable cause?

How to check, if the record once is processed from Consumer Side is committed when we send `Acknowledgement.acknowledge();`

**Consumer - properties**

```
Enable Auto commit = false;
Auto offset Reset = earliest;
max poll records = 1;
max poll interval ms config = I am calculating the value of this parameter at runtime from the formula ==>> (number_of_retries * x * 2) <= INTEGER.MaxValue
```

**Retry Policy - Simple**

```
number of retries = 3;
interval between retries = x (millis)
```

I am creating Topics at runtime on consumer side via beans `NewTopic(topic_name, 1, (**short**)1)`

There are 2 Kafka clusters and 1 zookeeper instances running.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

That broker is very old; if a consumer receives no records for 24 hours, the offsets were removed and restarting the consumer would cause it to reprocess all the records.

With newer brokers, it was changed to 7 days and the consumer has to be stopped for 7 days for the offsets to be removed.

Spring Boot 1.4.x (and even 1.5.x, 2.0.x) is no longer supported; the current version is 2.3.1.

You should upgrade to a newer broker and a more recent Spring Boot version.